# Tomcat 7 Cluster with loadbalancing only needs to run a service only on one node

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, scheduled-tasks, load-balancing, scheduler

The Tomcat cluster is configured as load balancer only. There is no session replication. So in case a Tomcat node on which the user session is running, dies in that case the session is lost.

We do need to run a service on that cluster periodically. Obviously it cannot run on both servers, but at the same time one has to ensure it has to be run on at least one server after certain interval.

What is an elegant solution in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) with [clustering](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering) support. You only need to define the cluster properties in your app and create some tables to store the job configuration in the database.

When a node in the cluster starts, it will make a call to the database, anouncing to be alive.

When a job has to be executed, periodically or      abnormally, only one of the nodes in the cluster will start executing the job. If the job fails or the node crashes, it can be restarted.